# Solr - Boost if id included in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I am trying to add query time boost if id of the record included in a given array.

```
ids = [1, 2, 3]
Product.solr_search do
  fulltext search_params do
    boost(50.0) { with(:id, ids) }
  end
  order_by(:score, :desc)
  paginate(offset: search_options[:offset], per_page: search_options[:page_limit])
end
```

What is the correct syntax to boost records that meet the condition of being included in the array?
In the real app I have arrays with 100+ elements. With the above syntax was able to boost only when the array is only 2-3 elements.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax in the question is working, but for no obvious reason I had to add ridiculously big boost number for it to work.

```
boost(500000) { with(:id, ids) }
```